# Objective-c decode UInt8 array of unsigned chars

Tags: objective-c, utf-16, uint

I'm trying to decode the following object, the variable is called `data` and is of type `UInt8`.

```
(UInt8 [520]) data = {
  [0] = '\xff'
  [1] = '\0'
  [2] = '2'
  [3] = '\0'
  [4] = 'H'
  [5] = '\0'
  [6] = 'o'
  [7] = '\0'
  [8] = 's'
  [9] = '\0'
  [10] = 't'
  [11] = '\0'
  [12] = 'e'
  [13] = '\0'
  [14] = 'd'
  [15] = '\0'
  [16] = ' '
  [17] = '\0'
  [18] = 'o'
  [19] = '\0'
  [20] = 'n'
  [21] = '\0'
  [22] = ' '
  [23] = '\0'
  [24] = 'D'
  [25] = '\0'
  [26] = 'i'
  [27] = '\0'
  [28] = 'g'
  [29] = '\0'
  [30] = 'i'
  [31] = '\0'
  [32] = 't'
  [33] = '\0'
  [34] = 'a'
  [35] = '\0'
  [36] = 'l'
  [37] = '\0'
  [38] = ' '
  [39] = '\0'
  [40] = 'O'
  [41] = '\0'
  [42] = 'c'
  [43] = '\0'
  [44] = 'e'
  [45] = '\0'
  [46] = 'a'
  [47] = '\0'
  [48] = 'n'
  [49] = '\0'
  [50] = '.'
  [51] = '\0'
  [52] = ' '
  [53] = '\0'
  [54] = 'M'
  [55] = '\0'
  [56] = 'a'
  [57] = '\0'
  [58] = 'n'
  [59] = '\0'
  [60] = 'a'
  [61] = '\0'
  [62] = 'g'
  [63] = '\0'
  [64] = 'e'
  [65] = '\0'
  [66] = 'd'
  [67] = '\0'
  [68] = ' '
  [69] = '\0'
  [70] = 'w'
  [71] = '\0'
  [72] = 'i'
  [73] = '\0'
  [74] = 't'
  [75] = '\0'
  [76] = 'h'
  [77] = '\0'
  [78] = ' '
  [79] = '\0'
  [80] = 'P'
  [81] = '\0'
  [82] = 'u'
  [83] = '\0'
  [84] = 'p'
  [85] = '\0'
  [86] = 'p'
  [87] = '\0'
  [88] = 'e'
  [89] = '\0'
  [90] = 't'
  [91] = '\0'
  [92] = '!'
  [93] = '\0'
  [94] = '\xa7'
  [95] = '\0'
  [96] = '0'
  [97] = '\0'
  [98] = '\xa7'
  [99] = '\0'
  [100] = '2'
  [101] = '\0'
  [102] = '0'
  [103] = '\0'
  [104] = '\xa9'
  [105] = '\x14'
  [106] = '\x0e'
  [107] = '\x02'
  [108] = '\x01'
  [109] = '\0'
  [110] = '\0'
  [111] = '\0'
  [112] = '\xe3'
  [113] = ' '
  [114] = '\x0e'
  [115] = '\x02'
  [116] = '\x01'
  [117] = '\0'
  [118] = '\0'
  [119] = '\0'
  [120] = '\xe8'
  [121] = '\xc3'
  [122] = '\x85'
  [123] = '\x01'
  [124] = '\x01'
  [125] = '\0'
  [126] = '\0'
  [127] = '\0'
  [128] = '\0'
  [129] = '\xc3'
  [130] = '\x85'
  [131] = '\x01'
  [132] = '\x01'
  [133] = '\0'
  [134] = '\0'
  [135] = '\0'
  [136] = '\xc8'
  [137] = 'P'
  [138] = '\0'
  [139] = '\0'
  [140] = '\x01'
  [141] = '\0'
  [142] = '\0'
  [143] = '\0'
  [144] = '`'
  [145] = '\xc3'
  [146] = '\xbf'
  [147] = '_'
  [148] = '\xff'
  [149] = '\x7f'
  [150] = '\0'
  [151] = '\0'
  [152] = 'a'
  [153] = '"'
  [154] = '\x0e'
  [155] = '\x02'
  [156] = '\x01'
  [157] = '\0'
  [158] = '\0'
  [159] = '\0'
  [160] = '\xf8'
  [161] = '\xc3'
  [162] = '\x85'
  [163] = '\x01'
  [164] = '\x01'
  [165] = '\0'
  [166] = '\0'
  [167] = '\0'
  [168] = '\xfc'
  [169] = '\xc3'
  [170] = '\x85'
  [171] = '\x01'
  [172] = '\x01'
  [173] = '\0'
  [174] = '\0'
  [175] = '\0'
  [176] = '\xa0'
  [177] = '>'
  [178] = '\x85'
  [179] = '\x01'
  [180] = '\0'
  [181] = '\0'
  [182] = '\0'
  [183] = '\0'
  [184] = '\xe8'
  [185] = '\xc3'
  [186] = '\x85'
  [187] = '\x01'
  [188] = '\x01'
  [189] = '\0'
  [190] = '\0'
  [191] = '\0'
  [192] = '\xe8'
  [193] = '\xc3'
  [194] = '\x85'
  [195] = '\x01'
  [196] = '\x01'
  [197] = '\0'
  [198] = '\0'
  [199] = '\0'
  [200] = '\0'
  [201] = '\xc4'
  [202] = '\x85'
  [203] = '\x01'
  [204] = '\x01'
  [205] = '\0'
  [206] = '\0'
  [207] = '\0'
  [208] = '\0'
  [209] = '\0'
  [210] = '\0'
  [211] = '\0'
  [212] = '\0'
  [213] = '\0'
  [214] = '\0'
  [215] = '\0'
  [216] = '\x80'
  [217] = '6'
  [218] = 'O'
  [219] = '\0'
  [220] = '\0'
  [221] = '\0'
  [222] = '\0'
  [223] = '\0'
  [224] = '@'
  [225] = '\0'
  [226] = '\0'
  [227] = '\0'
  [228] = '\0'
  [229] = '6'
  [230] = 'O'
  [231] = '\0'
  [232] = '\0'
  [233] = '\xc3'
  [234] = '\xbf'
  [235] = '_'
  [236] = '\xff'
  [237] = '\x7f'
  [238] = '\0'
  [239] = '\0'
  [240] = '\xfc'
  [241] = '\xc3'
  [242] = '\x85'
  [243] = '\x01'
  [244] = '\x01'
  [245] = '\0'
  [246] = '\0'
  [247] = '\0'
  [248] = '\0'
  [249] = '\xc4'
  [250] = '\x85'
  [251] = '\x01'
  [252] = '\x01'
  [253] = '\0'
  [254] = '\0'
  [255] = '\0'
  ...
}
```

I'm using this code to convert to an `NSString`.

```
NSString *info =[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data length:sizeof(data) encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

But I'm just getting foreign characters and wing-dings in the output.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm only interested in the first 3 sections separated by `'\xa7'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I should've used

`NSString *info =[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data length:sizeof(data) encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];`

Comment: Are you sure all that data is a string?  The initial 0x00ff looks dodgy and so does the data following what clearly is a string.

Comment: Thinking about it, the first 2 bytes looks like the length of the rest of the string?

Comment: Im sure not all of it is a string, but I'm not sure how I should be decoding it.

Comment: Well you should know what it is, in order to use it.

Comment: I'm only interested in the string components.